# Placing symbol in the center of button

Tags: android, android-button

I'm trying to set '+' symbol in a center of my button, but it is on the bottom

```
<Button android:background="@drawable/zoom_button_background"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black2"
        android:text="+"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

I want to set textSize to 42sp, but when I do this, plus is not in the center. How can I make him to be in a center?

Comment: look at my above comment. just use this attribute and let me know what happen.

Comment: This solution does not works too

Comment: change layout_width and layout_height to wrap_content and run if success then tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the text size you set (42sp) is too big for given size of the button (40dp x 40dp). Do not set the size of the button explicitly, use `wrap_content` instead, both for width and height.

Comment: Do not forget to run Clean on your project

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Button android:background="@drawable/zoom_button_background"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black2"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" >
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton will be best choice for this , because background have nothing to do with gravity .

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/zoom_button_background" />
```